# Reading XML files with different formats in PowerShell

Tags: xml, namespaces, powershell-2.0

I have written a script to read an XML in PowerShell 2.0...simple no problem. Howver, the problem I'm having is the client is sending the same XML in 2 different formats (see below). When I originally started developing I only had a file in format 1. So my powershell code looked like:

```
  [xml]$private:xmlFile = Get-Content $File
  $private:Request = $xmlFile.Request
  $Request.Action # returns Initialization
```

Now my code doesn't work with format 2 because it requires I use $Request.Action.InnerText or $Request.Action.'#ntext'

Anyone know an easy way to be able to handle both xml formats?

Format 1 (namespaces defined in root):

```
<temp:Request xmlns:ext="http://...">
        <ext:FileInformation>
            <ext:FileDetailsMetadata>
                <core:TransmissionID>TransmissionID0</core:TransmissionID>
                <core:SenderID>SenderID</core:SenderID>
                <core:ReceiverID>ReceiverID</core:ReceiverID>
            </ext:FileDetailsMetadata>
        <ext:Action>Initialization</ext:Action>
        </ext:FileInformation> 
   </temp:Request>
```

Format 2 (namespace defined in each node):

```
    <temp:Request xmlns:temp="http://..."> 
        <ext:FileInformation xmlns:ext="http://...">
            <ext:FileDetailsMetadata>
                <ns2:TransmissionID xmlns:ns2="http://...">TransmissionId</ns2:TransmissionID>
                <ns2:SenderID xmlns:ns2="...">SenderID</ns2:SenderID>
                <core:ReceiverID xmlns:core="http://...">930989307</core:ReceiverID>
            </ext:FileDetailsMetadata>
            <ns3:Action xmlns:ns3="http://...">Initialization</ns3:Action>          </ext:FileInformation>
</temp:Request>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a function to handle the various ways that the xml node data can be parsed.

Thanks